# Micronaut with Eclipse/JNosql

Tags: micronaut, jnosql

Is is possible to use Micronaut with JNoSQL ?
JNoSQL is depending on CDI implementatio i.e Weld, Micronaut support many of the same set of annotations, but I do not think it is exposing a full CDI container, so the question is it possible to use some of the JNoSQL goodness with Micronaut ?

Thank you.
Luis Oscar

Answer (score 2):

If Micronaut implements CDI 2.0 or higher it will work.
However, I think it works with Spring as the engine. Eclipse JNoSQL has the initiative to work with Spring Data soon.